Why would an AFT scale parameter be negative?
I am fitting an accelerated failure time (AFT) model to survival data, so:

where  are the survival times,  is a standard normal variable, and  is a vector of covariates.  Importantly,   is the so-called scale parameter.
When I fit this model to my data in R using survival::survreg(), setting dist = "lognormal", the scale parameter estimate is returned as -2.79.
At first I was confused, assuming that the scale parameter had to be positive.  But then I realised that this was mistaken; given the above formula, there's no reason it has to be non-negative; it is not a standard deviation.
But then I thought on it more and I was confusued again: even though it doesn't have to be non-negative, why would it ever need to be negative?  Because  is a normal variable,  and  have identical distributions.
If you solve the above for  we get:

which is also the same whether we use  or  .  (I had to do some plots to convince myself of this, but it is certainly true).
What am I missing?

This type of formulation of an accelerated failure time (AFT) survival model uses $\sigma$ as a scale parameter describing the width of the random distribution* around the fixed values of $\ln(T)$ given by the linear predictor $\alpha+\beta^T x$. Scale parameters in general are taken to have inherently positive values.
That said, you are correct to a certain extent. There is no inherent need for $\sigma$ to be positive in the equation that you have written. With a symmetric random distribution like the normal you would get the same distribution around the values of $\ln(T)$ given by the linear predictor. That doesn't hold, however, with asymmetric distributions like the minimum extreme value random distribution that corresponds to a Weibull model.
Furthermore, the  survreg() function estimates a coefficient for Log(scale), which is then exponentiated to give Scale:
library(survival)
model1 <- survreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx, ovarian)
summary(model1)
# 
# Call:
# survreg(formula = Surv(futime, fustat) ~ ecog.ps + rx, data = ovarian)
#              Value Std. Error     z       p
# (Intercept)  6.897      1.178  5.86 4.7e-09
# ecog.ps     -0.385      0.527 -0.73    0.47
# rx           0.529      0.529  1.00    0.32
# Log(scale)  -0.123      0.252 -0.49    0.62
# 
# Scale= 0.884

That requires scale to have a positive value in practice.
If you somehow got a negative value for Scale itself from a survreg() model I'd be curious to see the model summary.

*$X$ in your example. To avoid confusion between $x$ and $X$ it might be better to use a different symbol like $W$ for the baseline random distribution whose width is given by $\sigma$.

thank you so much for your answer.  I have been thinking on this all day and I think I have the solution.  I suspect the original model equation was wrong, or at least it is not what is being fitted by survreg.  I think survreg is fitting $ln(T) = \alpha + \beta^{T}x + exp(\sigma)W$, which would, I think, bring together and explain all the conficting opinions here so far.  However, I have been unable to find out precisely what survreg is fitting, so if anyone is able to help that would be fantastic.

If you have the survival package loaded and just type survreg at the R prompt (that is, without calling it as a function) then its code is printed. That function internally calls other functions. Some might not normally be exported from the package but can be accessed by typing survival:::functionName, while others are C code that you can inspect from the source code, which is linked from the main survival package page.

This paper shows the general log-likelihood form for an AFT model in Equation 2. The scale parameter (called $b$ in the paper) contributes to the log-likelihood in the form $-m\log b$, where $m$ is the number of events.

All incredibly useful.  Using a combination of the R code and the C code (difficult, as I do not know C) I am 90% certain that the model in my comment above was correct.  That is, survival::survreg is fitting $ln(T)=\alpha+\beta Tx+exp(\sigma)W$, i.e. $\sigma$ in this model is what survreg is calling Log(scale).
